# Login loop on Debian 12

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu

I have a login loop error on Debian 12
The final edit on the system that I made was:su root
nano /etc/sudoers
user_name ALL=(ALL)  ALL
Since I can't use sudo command I did so according to the instructions on the internet, after I shutdown and reopened I couldn't login, I've seen a few solutions online, but none of them work. i used (Ctrl+Alt+F2) but can't use any command there except "cd" command
Ls command not found
Nano command not found
Sudo command not found
Apt command not found
Anyone know about this incident? My ssd drive is more than 100Gb free and hhd drive is 1Tb free.

Comment: The GUI login is probably failing for the same reason you are getting the command not found errors.  At a guess, either your path is corrupt or you have destroyed something critical to running commands.  Can you type `/bin/ls` or similar to run the commands directly?

Comment: have you tried booting in recovery mode?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to a `PATH` issue. The `cd` command is working, because it is probably the `bash` builtin version used on your system.

If you can log in as `user_name` to other tty (using `CTRL`+`ALT`+`Fx` as you said), check content of your path by typing:

```bash
echo $PATH
```

If this command fails, as suggested in the comments, try passing full path to your command, eg:

```bash
/bin/echo $PATH
```

For comparison, here is the content of my `$PATH`:

```bash
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Does the problem appears for all users ?

I don't know if you're familiar with UNIX/Linux environnements, but just in case, be sure to type your commands all lowercase (in your question you say `Sudo` instead of `sudo`), as the *bash* interpreter is case sensitive.

Try also to check the content of your `/bin` directory, just to check if everything is fine:

```bash
ls /bin # or /bin/ls /bin
```

It is a lot safer to use [`visudo`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/sudo/visudo.8.en.html) when modifying the `sudoers` file:

```bash
su - root
visudo
# or to use a non-default editor
EDITOR=vim visudo
```

Why ? Because it will check you didn't made any mistake in the file, preventing system break. If it finds some error, it will not save the file, keeping your system's rights fine.

In case all of these tries above fails, use a livecd to recover your system:

- https://wiki.debian.org/RescueLive

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear: Apt, should be apt, Ls should be ls, and Nano should be nano.

A remedy for login loop used here some time ago:

```
rm ~/.Xauthority
```

and then:

```
service lightdm restart
```

Replace lightdm in the command with the relevant display manager if necessary.

If the filesystem isn't accessible via a console terminal, then a live distro or rescue disk can gain the required access. System may need a reboot after removing .Xauthority.